# Prove the function of 2 variables is not convex

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, matrix-calculus

I am trying to prove that the following function is not convex
https://github.com/epfml/ML_course/blob/master/lectures/10/lecture10a_matrix_factorization.pdf

$L = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{(d,n) \subset observed} (x_{dn} - (WZ^T)_{dn})^2 $

I am trying to set up the hessian but im not sure how to do it for a function with vectors as its variables. **Can I remove the sum and assume that everything is 1 dimensional** ? If yes:

$L = \frac{1}{2} (x - wd)^2 $

$\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial w^2} = z^2$

$\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial z^2} = w^2$

$\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial w \partial z} = -x + 2wz$

The function is convex if its Hessian is positive semidefinite. What would my next step look like ? Trying to show that $v^THv \ge 0$ looks really difficult here.

Comment: A 2x2 symmetric matrix is positive semidefinite if the diagonal entries are nonnegative and also the determinant. To show you are not convex, just come up with $z$ and $w$ to violate the determinant non negativity.

Comment: @max_zorn cool thanks ! So with regards to my first question in bold, I can remove the sum and assume everything is 1 dimensional ? Then if the hessian of that 1 dimensional case if not positive semidefinite then the version where w and z are vectors will not be positive semidefinite as well ?

Comment: Hi @kong you should be able to "embed" the one-dimensional counterexample into higher dimensions. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If a function is convex then it must be convex on all possible subspaces. Assume WLOG that $(1,1)\in(observed)$ and take the subspaces:
$$
{\cal W}_{11}=\{W\colon W_{dn}=0,\ (d,n)\ne(1,1)\}
$$
and similar for ${\cal Z}_{11}$. On this subspace the function is what you wrote
$$
L=\frac12(x-wz)^2+\text{const}
$$
where $w=W_{11}$ and $z=Z_{11}$. If you can prove that this $L$ is not convex then the overall function cannot be convex either.

Proof: take two points $(w,z)=\pm(x,1)$. At those points the function is zero. If the function is convex the graph must be under the zero, however, $L>0$ in between (can you show that?). It works well with the Hessian matrix too.

Comment: great so if i can prove that it is convex on a subspace then it still is convex if w and z are now vectors ?